# Query by item in array of document, and sort by item's position in the array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `dinosaurs` with documents of this structure:

`doc#1:`

```
    name: "Tyrannosaurus rex",
    dominantColors: [
        "beige",
        "blue",
        "green"
      ]
```

`doc#2:`

```
    name: "Velociraptor",
    dominantColors: [
        "green",
        "orange",
        "white"
      ]
```

I want to query the collection by color name (for example: `green`) to get documents sorted by color's position in `dominantColors` array. First get the documents in which `green` occurs higher in the array, then those in which it is lower. So, in the provided case I would get `doc#2` first, then `doc#1`.

Each `dominantColors` array contains 3 elements, with elements sorted from most dominant to least.

I am looking through documentation, but am not able to find a solution. Maybe I need a different data structure altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Firestore doesn't support querying arrays by ranked index.  The only way you can query an array is using an array-contains type query.

What you could do instead is organize your colors using maps where the color is the key and their rank is the value:

```
name: "Tyrannosaurus rex",
dominantColors: {
    "beige": 1,
    "blue": 2,
    "green": 3
}
```

Then you can order the query by the value of the map's property.  So, in JavaScript, it would be something like this:

```
firebase
    .collection('dinosaurs')
    .where('dominantColors.green', '>', 0)
    .orderBy('dominantColors.green')
```